# Como Interagir(ler/escrever) com uma Aplicação Web Que Abre Apenas Dentro De Um Browser Específico

Tags: javascript, automatização

**CONTEXTO**

Eu uso uma aplicação web que só funciona com o `IE8` para gerenciamento de clientes. Então eu desenvolvi um `script` para `AutoIt` para fazer o trabalho. Ele funciona muito bem e minha empresa prospera.

Mas recentemente, a empresa proprietária desta aplicação web, anunciou que a única maneira de acessar este aplicativo web será através de um novo navegador web, que foi desenvolvido especificamente para trabalhar com esta aplicação.

Este novo navegador não tem ferramentas de desenvolvedor para mostrar códigos como `html`, `javascript`, `css`, etc.

Então, meu bot não vai funcionar corretamente, porque eu preciso ler e escrever para esta página, não posso confiar apenas nas **coordenadas X e Y** , pois os dados estão sempre mudando, dropdowns, pop-ups de confirmação / erro, etc.

**QUESTÃO**

Como posso interagir (ler / escrever) com esta aplicação web?

- **Ler de (página principal e pop-up):** Caixa de texto, select, radiobutton, checkbox, etc.
- **Escrever / Simular Clique / para (página principal e pop-up):** Caixa de texto, select, radiobutton, checkbox, etc.

**NOTA**

- Não é obrigatório que a solução funcione com `AutoIt`, aceito qualquer solução(não preciso de um código pronto, apenas uma luz, pois pesquisei e não encontrei nada desse tipo) desde que ela funcione (leitura / gravação).
- O nome do navegador é **ASCWebBrowser**, mas você não será capaz de baixá-lo, porque é apenas para os proprietários parceiros de negócios.

Eu não tenho ideia, sobre qual tag incluir.

Comment: Acho incrível como as pessoas se preocupam mais em dar downvote do que sugerir melhoria para a pergunta.

Comment: Normalmente o controle de qual navegador é usado vem da informação que vai no cabeçalho da requisição chamada "User-Agent". No caso se você não tem ferramentas de desenvolvedor, você vai ter que usar um sniffer de rede para descobrir qual você deve usar. Um programa que você pode usar pra fazer isso é o [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)

Comment: Eu verifiquei e identifiquei que no momento, o navegador AscWebBrowser utiliza como User-Agent "IE" e a versão "7".

Comment: Conseguiu resolver com isso então?

Comment: Utilizei Fiddler 4 para "cheirar" as requisições https e ele conseguiu capturar com sucesso o html dessa página que precisei acessar a partir disso, utilizei esse html no meu bot e ele funcionou normalmente.